# efi does not detect any operating systems

Tags: uefi, fedora-25

I have a Lenovo ideapad 310-15KIB with windows 10 preinstalled in UEFI mode.

I have tried to install fedora 25 workstation in legacy mode (bios) an error occurred during install telling me that fedora won't boot and asked me if I want to quit the installation and I clicked yes.

After that the system does not detect windows  nor any other OS that I install (I tried reinstalling windows, Ubuntu etc...) nothing shows up in EFI or legacy mode it simply says missing operating system. The EFI partition type is GPT.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should not install an os in legacy mode and another in UEFI. That does simply not work.

Another question: Did the hard drives get detected properly ? I read elsewere that this can cause problems.

That said. I would guess fedora overwrote your boot sector and so the Windows UEFI is lost for now because it got overwritten with legacy mode.

Fist you have to decice if you want to install Fedora in legacy mode, then set the bios to boot in legacy and only in legacy and then try to install again. (Windows will not work in legacy.)

If you want dual boot. Set the Bios to UEFI only and install Windows first, then fedora in UEFI mode again. It should detect Windows and make it bootable with grub.

Also for Fedora install it would be wise to deactivate secure boot.

If this does not help. Please provide the error messages you encounter!

Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When installing Windows on UEFI-based PCs using Windows Setup, your hard drive partition style must be set up to support either UEFI mode or legacy BIOS-compatibility mode.

For example, if you receive the error message: “Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is not of the GPT partition style”, it’s because your PC is booted in UEFI mode, but your hard drive is not configured for UEFI mode.

refer below link
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn336946.aspx